# Counting the number of times a value exists in a column in SQL and 0 if it doesn't based on two columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the number of wins a team had in their conference tournament. Part of the SQL table I'm using is listed below:

```
   Season ConfAbbrev DayNum WTeamID LTeamID
1   2001    a_sun     121   1194    1144
2   2001    a_sun     121   1416    1240
3   2001    a_sun     122   1209    1194
4   2001    a_sun     122   1359    1239
5   2001    a_sun     122   1391    1273
6   2001    a_sun     122   1407    1416
7   2001    a_sun     123   1209    1359
8   2001    a_sun     123   1407    1391
9   2001    a_sun     124   1209    1407
```

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT season, confabbrev, wteamid, COUNT(wteamid) AS wins
INTO conf_tourney_wins
FROM mconferencetourneygames
GROUP BY season, confabbrev, wteamid
ORDER BY season, confabbrev;
```

I can get the number of wins a team has. The problem is that I also want the teams that didn't win a game listed with 0 in the wins column. I think I need to use a CASE statement but haven't been able to get one to work. I tried using something like:

```
WHEN lteamid NOT IN wteamid THEN 0
```

but that didn't work. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: please table with appropriate database platform

Comment: Sample data *and* desired results are useful.

Answer (score 1):

if there is a table for teams the answer of Gordon Linoff is true.but if there is not ,you can write:

```
select grp.season, grp.confabbrev, grp.TeamID,count(g.wteamID)
from
    (SELECT season, confabbrev, wteamid as teamID
     FROM mconferencetourneygames
     GROUP BY season, confabbrev, wteamid
     union
     SELECT season, confabbrev, Lteamid as TeamID
     FROM mconferencetourneygames
     GROUP BY season, confabbrev, Lteamid
    ) grp
left outer join mconferencetourneygames m
on(g.season = grp.season and g.confabbrev = grp.confabbrev and g.wteamid = 
grp.teamid)
GROUP BY grp.season, grp.confabbrev, grp.TeamID
ORDER BY grp.season, grp.confabbrev;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I did have a teams list and that probably would have worked as well but this was nice because it selected all the teams listed in either column. I did remove the `distinct` call because I wanted to count the number of times the teamid was in the wteamid column. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with a list of all teams.  Let me assume you have this in a table.  Then . . . `left join`.  So, this seems to do what you want -- including *all* teams with `0` for the ones who have no wins:

```
SELECT ctw.season, ctw.confabbrev, t.wteamid, COUNT(c.teamid) AS wins
INTO conf_tourney_wins
FROM teams t LEFT JOIN
     mconferencetourneygames ctg
     ON ctg.wteamid = t.teamid
GROUP BY  ctw.season, ctw.confabbrev, t.wteamid
ORDER BY season, confabbrev;
```